SQLite3 - Error LNK1120 unresolved external elements: 8
I'm making a program that uses the windows.h and sqlite3.h dependencies to decrypt cookie files into a readable form (if you give advice on this, I would also be very grateful). I connect sqlite3.h by specifying the local path. I get 8 LNK2019 errors when compiling, namely with sqlite3.h functions, while the functions themselves are defined (when I remove include sqlite3.h I get 40 other errors about undefined functions). I would like to note that the error is caused by the file WindowsAPI.obj. What could be causing my error LNK2019, perhaps incorrect include sqlite3.h, but how can I fix it then?
#include <iostream>
#include <C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/libraries/sqlite-amalgamation-3460000/sqlite3.h> 
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <sstream> 

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Details
Error LNK1120 8 unresolved external elements WindowsAPI C:\Users\ivans\source\repos\WindowsAPI\x64\Debug\WindowsAPI.exe 1
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol sqlite3_close referenced in function main WindowsAPI C:\Users\ivans\source\repos\WindowsAPI\WindowsAPI\WindowsAPI.obj 1
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol sqlite3_column_blob referenced in function main WindowsAPI C:\Users\ivans\source\repos\WindowsAPI\WindowsAPI\WindowsAPI.obj 1
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol sqlite3_column_bytes referenced in function main WindowsAPI C:\Users\ivans\source\repos\WindowsAPI\WindowsAPI\WindowsAPI.obj 1
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol sqlite3_column_text referenced in function main WindowsAPI C:\Users\ivans\source\repos\WindowsAPI\WindowsAPI\WindowsAPI.obj 1
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol sqlite3_finalize referenced in function main WindowsAPI C:\Users\ivans\source\repos\WindowsAPI\WindowsAPI\WindowsAPI.obj 1
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol sqlite3_open referenced in function main WindowsAPI C:\Users\ivans\source\repos\WindowsAPI\WindowsAPI\WindowsAPI.obj 1
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol sqlite3_prepare_v2 referenced in function main WindowsAPI C:\Users\ivans\source\repos\WindowsAPI\WindowsAPI\WindowsAPI.obj 1
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol sqlite3_step referenced in function main WindowsAPI C:\Users\ivans\source\repos\WindowsAPI\WindowsAPI\WindowsAPI.obj 1

I talked to AI, they told me to add the path to the project dependencies, but I can only add .lib files there, which is not there for sqlite3 (there is only sqlite3.h, sqlite3.c, sqlite3ext.h, shell.c).

You need to add sqlite3.c to your project. You should also copy all sqlite source and header files to your project directory before adding anything.
Sqlite is a little unusual in that it is not distributed as a library, rather it is distributed as source files which you are expected to incorporate into your project directly.
